# Conducting wire swinging in magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential

Imagine a situation where a conducting wire is swinging around one of its ends, in a uniform magnetic field that is perpendicular to the plane of rotation, and i want to find the potential that is generated across the wire.

My approach was to find the force given the distance from the center of rotation, that is the Lorentz force. $$F(r) = wrB\ dQ$$
Where $dQ$ is the charge stored in an infinitely small segment of the wire.

Then i find the electric field dividing out by $dQ$.

To find the potential I integrate the electric field from $0$ to $l$(length of wire) $$V = \int_{0}^{l}wrB\ dr$$
So, solving the integral $$V = wBl^2/2$$

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Why are you unsure about your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, but I'm not comfortable with your use of dQ.  At equilibrium, the magnetic force on any charge (such as an electron) in the wire wrBq is balanced by a radial electric force qE.  This gives E(r)  = wrB which can be integrated to get the potential difference.